# CoreData update not working using MagicalRecord

Tags: objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord-2.2

I am trying to update an existing CoreData entity using MagicalRecord (version 2.3); this is my code:

```
PreferenceData *updateData = [PreferenceData MR_createEntityInContext:defaultContext];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"aHourFormat == %@ || aHourFormat == %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt: 12], [NSNumber numberWithInt: 24]];
updateData = [PreferenceData MR_findFirstWithPredicate: predicate inContext: defaultContext];

NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *staffNamesArray = [[userDefaults arrayForKey:@"staffNamesArray"] mutableCopy];
NSMutableDictionary *preferencesDict = [[userDefaults dictionaryForKey:@"preferencesDictionary"] mutableCopy];

NSMutableArray *addlSvcsArray = [self createAddlSvcsTextboxArray];
NSMutableArray *customServicesArray = [[userDefaults arrayForKey:@"customServicesArray"] mutableCopy];

updateData.aStaffPos1 = staffNamesArray[0];
updateData.aStaffPos2 = staffNamesArray[1];
updateData.aStaffPos3 = staffNamesArray[2];
updateData.aStaffPos4 = staffNamesArray[3];
updateData.aStaffPos5 = staffNamesArray[4];
updateData.aStaffPos6 = staffNamesArray[5];

updateData.aShopOpens = [preferencesDict objectForKey:@"shopOpens"];
updateData.aShopCloses = [preferencesDict objectForKey:@"shopCloses"];

updateData.aDeleteOldAppts = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[oDeleteAfterXDays.text intValue]];
updateData.aHourFormat = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[preferencesDict objectForKey:@"timeFormat"]];
updateData.aServicesType = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[preferencesDict objectForKey:@"servicesType"]];
updateData.aShowApptServices = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: @0];
updateData.aColorScheme = [preferencesDict objectForKey:@"colorScheme"];
updateData.aUpdatedRecordFlag = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: @1];

updateData.aAddlSvcs1 = addlSvcsArray[0];
updateData.aAddlSvcs2 = addlSvcsArray[1];
updateData.aAddlSvcs3 = addlSvcsArray[2];
updateData.aAddlSvcs4 = addlSvcsArray[3];
updateData.aAddlSvcs5 = addlSvcsArray[4];
updateData.aAddlSvcs6 = addlSvcsArray[5];

[defaultContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if(success)
        NSLog(@"update successful");
    else
        NSLog(@"update failed");
}];

}
```

I get no errors; the data is in the variables, but when I look at the record using *sqlitebrowser*, nothing has changed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first create a new record in `updateData` then you overwrite this variable with a search result. Each time you run the update you will create a new record which will just have defaults or be empty.

If your data is not updated as expected, the `updateData` you fetch is most probably `nil` because something is wrong with the predicate.

Comment: It appears to be a logic error on my part... let me see what I can do with it and I'll get back to you... thank you for taking the time to respond, I appreciate it.

Comment: It was indeed a logic error; all of the updated data is in *userDefaults* before it gets to saving it to CoreData... thank you again... I appreciate it.